# Docker container cannot run

Tags: linux, docker

```
[frankchen@localhost ~]$ docker start sharelatex 
sharelatex
[frankchen@localhost ~]$ docker logs sharelatex
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_make_sharelatex_data_dirs.sh...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data/user_files’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data/compiles’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/data/cache’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/tmp’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/tmp’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/tmp’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/tmp/uploads’: No such file or directory
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/tmp’: Permission denied
chown: cannot access ‘/var/lib/sharelatex/tmp/dumpFolder’: No such file or directory
*** /etc/my_init.d/00_make_sharelatex_data_dirs.sh failed with status 1

*** Killing all processes...
```

Comment: try `sudo docker start sharelatex`

Comment: Looks like the shell script that is set to run at `docker start` (either by way of the `cmd` or `entrypoint`) is trying to run some commands that it does not have permission to do.

Comment: sudo docker start sharelatex does not work.

Comment: Sudo wouldn't work in this case, cause the problem is not on the host, but in the docker machine

Comment: Any information else needed?

Comment: Is this an image that you build yourself, or you pulled from somewhere?

Comment: What is strange is that the default user inside of docker containers should be root, as stated in http://www.yegor256.com/2014/08/29/docker-non-root.html.  Root should be able to make directories everywhere, except for a mounted volume (in which case it may/not be able to).  Can you try running `docker images`, find the ID of the image your container was based off of, and run `docker history --no-trunc IMAGE_ID`, and post the output?  Another thing to try is entering the container with `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash`, and try creating a directory with `mkdir /var/lib/sharelatex/data`.

Comment: @CtheGood That's not correct. Depends on the Dockerfile, it doesn't have to be `root`

Comment: That's true @warmoverflow, I should say, the default user is root, but the dockerfile could potentially change that.  It looks like https://github.com/sharelatex/sharelatex-docker-image/blob/master/Dockerfile does add a user and make permission changes to `/var/lib/sharelatex`, but it doesn't actually change the user quite yet.  There is a CMD that runs a script that potentially could change the user.  We would need to see the contents of `/sbin/my_init`.  @陈昭男, can enter the container `docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME bash` and run two commands `whoami` and `cat /sbin/my_init`?

Comment: @warmoverflow it's a official docker image of a project called sharelatex

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mounted a host folder to the image via `docker run -v` as instructed on the sharelatex website.

When the user that owns the host folder has a different uid than the Docker container user, you will have a permission problem where the Docker user cannot write to the mounted folder.

Solution 1: You need to find out the uid of the Docker container user, and on the host `chown` the mounted folder to a user with the same uid.

Solution 2: Alternatively, you can run the docker image without mounted folder. In that case your data are stored inside the container, and you need to make sure that you backup your data first if you delete the container.